# Air/Android - Download and load png file

Tags: android

I need code that will download a .png file and then load it to the stage.

The code below is the initial test version I am doing of this functionality, and it works on my PC but not on my Android tablet, and produces the following output and error:

---

onDownload_ResponseStatusHandler :: 200

onDownload_CompleteHandler

writeBytesToFile

File successfully downloaded

ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubble=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2035" errorID=2035]

---

```
    private function download(url:String):void {
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        urlRequest.url = url;

        var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onDownload_CompleteHandler);
        urlStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDownload_IOErrorHandler);
        urlStream.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS,onDownload_ResponseStatusHandler);
        urlStream.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,onDownload_SecurityHandler);   
        urlStream.load(urlRequest); 
    }

    protected function onDownload_CompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("onDownload_CompleteHandler");
        var urlStream:URLStream = event.currentTarget as URLStream;
        var outBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;         
        urlStream.readBytes(outBytes,0,urlStream.bytesAvailable);           
        writeBytesToFile(outBytes);
    }   


    private function writeBytesToFile(outBytes:ByteArray):void {
        trace("writeBytesToFile");
        saveStr = File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath+"/loginPlay_ro.png";
        var fileToWrite:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(saveStr);//Where you want store 

        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  
        fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onFileStream_CloseHandler);
        fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onFileStream_IOErrorHandler);
        fileStream.openAsync(fileToWrite, FileMode.WRITE);  
        fileStream.writeBytes(outBytes, 0, outBytes.length);
        fileStream.close();
    }

    protected function onFileStream_CloseHandler(event:Event = null):void {
        trace("File successfully downloaded ");
        fileComplete();
    }

    protected function onFileStream_IOErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("File can't downloaded file doesn't exist ");
    }

    protected function onDownload_SecurityHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void{
        trace("onDownload_SecurityHandler :: " + event.text);            
    }

    protected function onDownload_ResponseStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void{
        trace("onDownload_ResponseStatusHandler :: " + event.status);
    }

    protected function onDownload_IOErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("onDownload_IOErrorHandler :: " + event.text);            
    }

    private function fileComplete(e:Event=null){
        var localLoader = new Loader();
        localLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, localLoaded);
        localLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
        localLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        localLoader.load(new URLRequest(saveStr));
    }

    private function localLoaded(e:Event){
        trace("localLoaded");
        localHolder.addChild(e.target.content);
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, localLoaded);
    }

    private function initHandler(event:Event):void {
        var loader:Loader = Loader(event.target.loader);
        var info:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(loader.contentLoaderInfo);
        trace("initHandler: loaderURL=" + info.loaderURL + " url=" + info.url);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, as expected it was in the line:

localLoader.load(new URLRequest(saveStr));

It instead needs to be:

localLoader.load(new URLRequest("file://"+saveStr));